# Can I stop my allies from attacking me if I ally with the Grox?

Tags: spore

If I get an ally's friendship score up to about 250 before allying with the Grox, will they still instantly hate me and attack me or will they remain allies?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to have allies even if you are allies with the grox.

You may be REALLY good friends with them and still have a good relation with them, even after you ally the grox.

You can use a monolith to become allies with a new species, that will not give you a negative score for being allies with the grox, if they reach the space stage AFTER you became allies with the grox.

You can be in war with a species, until they ask you to not attack them anymore, that will make your relationship with them relatively neutral.

Comment: You can probably get a huge relationship bonus by making the grox go extinct. I have not tried this

Answer (score -1):

Old Spore forum posts seem to suggest it's possible to have neutral relations, especially with Zealots (since to ally the Grox you'll have used the planet buster which breaks galactic code and Zealots have a +50 relation bonus towards you for breaking code).

All the evidence is pretty much anecdotal, but it seems very unlikely/extremely difficult to have a friendship score greater than neutrality.

If you uplifted a race of Zealots and had gracious greeter you might be able to ally them.